# How to open a protected route on a new window in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage, react-router-dom

[The smarann app on this link, in this app, take-test page should open on a new window](https://lead.smarann.com)

[In this image, take-test route needs to open on a new window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS8NL.png)

I have tried to authenticate (which is checking the local storage where user details are saved) while opening on a new tab and then updating a state to verify that the user is authenticated and then rendering the protected component based on this state.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...otherProps}) => {
    const {isAuthenticated} = useAuth()
  const [isNewTabAuthenticated, setIsNewTabAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('smarann-user-data'));

    if(user.email) {
      setIsNewTabAuthenticated(true);
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Route
      render={() =>
        isAuthenticated === true || isNewTabAuthenticated === true ? (
          <Component   {...otherProps}/>
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

I have also tried running above useEffect in App.js file and updating the state there. But it is not re-rendering the page after updating the state to check whether it is authenticated or not.

This is the limitation of react-router-dom as the states are not updating on opening the route on a new window.
Can we achieve this using redux as the state manager and using redux's state persistent functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

I can't speak to the value of `isAuthenticated` from the `useAuth` hook on the initial render, but there is an issue with the local `isNewTabAuthenticated` state. The `useEffect` hook runs at the end of the render cycle, so by then it's too late to check localStorage and set the `isNewTabAuthenticated` state, the `false` value is used and the redirect is likely issued.

## Solution

Initialize the `isNewTabAuthenticated` state directly from localStorage. It's all synchronous code, so start with the correct initial state.

Example:

```
const PrivateRoute = props => {
  const {isAuthenticated} = useAuth();

  const [isNewTabAuthenticated, setIsNewTabAuthenticated] = useState(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('smarann-user-data'));

    return !!user?.email;
  });

  return isAuthenticated || isNewTabAuthenticated
    ? (
      <Route {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/" />
    );
};
```

You can check if the `useAuth` hook and state has a similar issue.

> Can we achieve this using redux as the state manager and using redux's
> state persistent functionality?

Yes, you certainly could. The redux state should also be persisted to some longer-term storage, typically localStorage. You might need additional "pending"/"loading" type logic if the auth state is checked on the initial app render.

Comment: Hey @DrewReese, I am here thanking you a lot for helping me with this issue. It was really awesome to get to know this correct approach so precisely and for letting me know the main reason of this issue.And I am also thankful for your insight on the redux's persistent state also.